# Responsive Images - crop don't seem to work

Tags: theme-development, images, responsive

most likely I didn't got the idea of responsive images right know, so please consider pointing out misunderstandings in that concept.

What I want to have:

I have a page where I query for custom post types and echo their titles and thumbnails. 
The custom image size is set to 300x225px and I ask wordpress to crop the images.
`add_image_size('custom_330_225', 330, 225, true);`

Part of the uploaded thumbnails are squares, some are very width but not that high. 
With the custom image size I imagine to get all images in 330x225px on that overview.

But no - they are in different proportions.

So I imagine the crop doesn't work. I read something about crop and responsive images but all in all I am a bit overhelmed by the responsive image feature.

As I put the images in three columns I really don't need images bigger than 330px - but WordPress puts bigger images in the imgsrc.

The images are also in completely different ratios - and I read somewhere that the responsive image feature only includes images in the same ratio.

And the image don't involve custom image sizes. Like we have 800x800px and 550x550px.

It would also be great to get a hint who to set up image sizes in a sane way. 
We use about 8 custom image sizes and I guess with responsive images this should be solved in another way.

Here is the link to the page: https://veganz.de/de/maerkte/

Comment: Have you tried [regenerating thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) for starters?

Comment: Yes - a couple of times. 
Doesn't solve my problem. 
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ok, but it looks [rather different now](https://veganz.de/de/maerkte/) from what it was. So I'm not quite sure what you're after now.

Comment: Now the page is, like it should be. 
And unfortunately I don't really know why.

Maybe another regenerate thumbnails helped - I don't know. But I would prefer to understand what has happened. 

This gist answered a couple of my questions: https://gist.github.com/kevinwhoffman/2d9a55d63d8505fe02c9

But all in all I feel like there is to little information about this new feature :/